What is the derivative of unit quaternion time derivative w.r.t. to unit quaternion and angular velocity?
I am trying to get the Jacobian matrix of continuous-time rigid body dynamics using unit quaternions.
The state vector is $x=\left[p, q, v, \omega\right]$. $p, v, \omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are position, linear & angular velocity in 3-D space, and $q$ is the attitude represented by unit quaternion. We can get the continuous dynamics $\dot{x}=f(x,u)$, and we know $\dot{q}=\frac{1}{1}q\otimes\hat{\omega}$, where $\hat{\omega}=\left[0, \omega\right]$.
I'm not sure how to handle $q$ when computing the Jacobian matrix. Specifically, I don't know how to calculate $\frac{\partial \dot{q}}{\partial q}$. I know how to naively compute this partial derivative directly and get a 4-by-4 matrix, but I don't think it is correct. I believe $\frac{\partial p}{\partial q}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial q}$ and $\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial q}$ are all $0$, but I am not sure about their dimensions.
Does anyone have some ideas?
